# How can I run several projects under the same solution in Visual Studio via script

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sequential, multiple-projects

I'm using vs2013.
I have one solution with 15 projects under it.
I need to run each project, in specific order, and can't run them parallel.
(need to wait until first one is finish, and only then run the second one, and so on..)
For now, I'm doing it manually, by right clicking on the project--> set as start project, and then click on Start.
Can I do it via script or something else, that will run the projects in the order I choose, one after the other, Sequentially?
*update:  I upload pictures of what I trying to do, with build dependencies and set startup projects.
1:
[image: set dependencies]

2:
[image: set startup order (choose multiple startup)]
(original, I choose multiple startUp)
3:
[image: running and get error]
Thanks.

I want "splitter" to run first, when it finish I want "DocCreator" and when it finish, I want "PdfCreator" to run

Answer (score 2):

You can right click your solution and click 'Project Dependencies' to set up the build order by stating which project depends on another.

After that you can right click your solution again and click 'Set StartUp Projects' to choose which projects will be run.

Comment: Thanks but it's not work. I get an error, "The debugger cannot continue running the process. unable to start debugging".
Maybe I did something wrong?
I will upload pictures.